# How to count change in row values in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Logic to count the change in the row values of a given column

Input

```
df22 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1,22.0), (1,22.0), (1,21.0), (1,20.0), (2, 3.0), (2,3.0), 
    (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0), (2,3.0), (3,11.0), (4, 11.0), (4,15.0), (1,22.0)],
    ("id", "v"))

+---+----+
| id|   v|
+---+----+
|  1| 1.0|
|  1|22.0|
|  1|22.0|
|  1|21.0|
|  1|20.0|
|  2| 3.0|
|  2| 3.0|
|  2| 5.0|
|  2|10.0|
|  2| 3.0|
|  3|11.0|
|  4|11.0|
|  4|15.0|
+---+----+
```

```
Expect output

+---+----+---+
| id|   v|  c|
+---+----+---+
|  1| 1.0|  0|
|  1|22.0|  1|
|  1|22.0|  1|
|  1|21.0|  2|
|  1|20.0|  3|
|  2| 3.0|  0|
|  2| 3.0|  0|
|  2| 5.0|  1|
|  2|10.0|  2|
|  2| 3.0|  3|
|  3|11.0|  0|
|  4|11.0|  0|
|  4|15.0|  1|
+---+----+---+
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance
Ramabadran

Answer (score 0):

Before adding answer, I would like to ask you ,"what you have tried ??". Please try something from your end and then seek for support in this platform. Also your question is not clear. You have not provided if you are looking for a delta capture count per 'id' or as a whole. Just giving an expected output is not going to make the question clear.

And now comes to your question , if I understood it correctly from the sample input and output,you need delta capture count per 'id'. So one way to achieve it as below

```
#Capture the incremented count using lag() and sum() over below mentioned window

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

winSpec=Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('v') # Your Window for capturing the incremented count


df22.\
withColumn('prev',F.coalesce(F.lag('v').over(winSpec),F.col('v'))).\
withColumn('c',F.sum(F.expr("case when v-prev<>0 then 1 else 0 end")).over(winSpec)).\
drop('prev').\
orderBy('id','v').\
show()

+---+----+---+
| id|   v|  c|
+---+----+---+
|  1| 1.0|  0|
|  1|20.0|  1|
|  1|21.0|  2|
|  1|22.0|  3|
|  1|22.0|  3|
|  1|22.0|  3|
|  2| 3.0|  0|
|  2| 3.0|  0|
|  2| 3.0|  0|
|  2| 5.0|  1|
|  2|10.0|  2|
|  3|11.0|  0|
|  4|11.0|  0|
|  4|15.0|  1|
+---+----+---+
```

Comment: Thanks Akhil ,  I was trying after converting to Pandas framework